# Magento 2 - Delete/update all products attribute values by attribute_code

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, delete

In Magento 2,

How to do a mass deletion of all products attribute values, by attribute_code.

For exemple I want to delete all values for attribute_code = "my_code".

**EDIT**

I also want to update products attribute values by attribute_code.

I found this :

```
$productActionObject = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action');
$productActionObject->updateAttributes($idArray, array('weight' => 15), 0);
```

But my weight values are different between each product ids.
I want to update attribute according to an array with product_id as key and weight as value:

```
$array[1] = 14;
$array[2] = 152;
$array[3] = 58;
...
```

I can't load every products, because there is a lot of values.

Thansk for your help

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

```
protected $_productCollectionFactory;
protected $_productRepository;

public function __construct(
    .......................................................
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    .......................................................

) {
    .......................................................
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    .......................................................
}

public function execute()
{
    $prdcollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $attributeCode = "Attribute_code";
    $attributeValue = "Attribute_Value"
    foreach ($prdcollection as $prdkey => $prdvalue) {
        $prdData = $this->_productRepository->getById($prdvalue->getId());
        $prdData->setCustomAttribute($attributeCode, $attributeValue);
        //$prdData->setData($attributeCode, $attributeValue);
        $this->_productRepository->save($prdData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not a solution for me. I don't want to make a one shot script.
But it's an import script run every day with a cronjob.

Comment: Please check my update answer. and update me.